# droppable background color to none not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have two div box , when i drag and drop box002 to another div box001, voxoo1 color should become none;

i want the background color to be changed to none in javascript. it tried jquery but didnt get it.

how can i achieve this?

```js
function allowDrop(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

```css
box001 {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #42e0fd;
}

box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -50px;
  right: 20px;
  float: left;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10" style="background-color: #42e0fd;">
  <p>8:30</p>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="1" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. to your question use this in `drop` function

   `document.getElementsByClassName('box001')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'initial';`

2.  You try to style with css using `className` so **use in css `.className{}` with `.` before.**

See code below and some fix in css:

```js
    function allowDrop(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev){
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();

      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

      var el = document.getElementById(data);

      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
     document.getElementsByClassName('box001')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    }
```

```css
    .box001 {
      float: left;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 10%;
      background-color: #42e0fd;
    }

    .box002 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: -50px;
    top: 76px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 217px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10" style="background-color: #42e0fd;">
      <p>8:30</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="1" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
    </div>
```

Comment: i have two div with same class name box001 with with id="1" and id="2",  want to add and drop another div with same class name box002 with id="3" to second box with id="2".

Comment: if possible reply

Answer (score 0):

In the drop function do something like this: `document.querySelector('.box001').style.backgroundColor = 'initial';`